# Decrypting hex string and getting non-hex characters when I try to print

Tags: python

In the code below I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted message given two messages encrypted with the same key (two-time pad).  The code works as I want it too until the last line where I try an print out the hex string as ascii.

I get the error:

```
    print result.decode('hex')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

The hex string that is causing the error is:

```
ab51e67kba7<4:72fd`d
```

Which has some non hex characters in it.  I'm not sure why it has the non-hex in it.  Or where to go from here.

Here's the full code:

```
# Messages
m1 = "31aa4573aa487946aa15"
m2 = "32510ba9babebbbefd00"

# Key
k = "6b6bdfa4rqggrgwereff"

guess = 'aa'
#guess = guess.encode('hex')
result = ''


def strxor(a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

# Make cipher texts
c1 = strxor(m1,k)
c2 = strxor(m2,k)

# xor of the two messages   
m1m2 = strxor(c1,c2)

# loop through each bit of the m1m2 message and xor against a test char or string
# see if any of the output makes sense
for e in range(0, len(m1), 2):
    subString = m1m2[e:e+2]
    try:
        result = result + "".join( strxor(subString, guess))
    except exception: 
        pass

#print hex and ascii results
print result
print result.decode('hex')
```

Comment: I just XOR two hex strings together.  That should give me another hex string?

Comment: are you sure you dont want result.encode('hex') ?

Answer (score 1):

Rewind just a little bit and look at what's in `c1`.

That is, run everything up through

```
# Messages
m1 = "31aa4573aa487946aa15"
m2 = "32510ba9babebbbefd00"

# Key
k = "6b6bdfa4rqggrgwereff"

guess = 'aa'
#guess = guess.encode('hex')
result = ''


def strxor(a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

# Make cipher texts
c1 = strxor(m1,k)
```

`c1` is `'\x05SW\x03PSV\x07\x13\x10S_E^CS\x13\x04WS'` in this case.

When `m1` and `k` are xor'ed, two strings of *ascii hexadecimal* digits have been xored. The result will definitely be out of the range you're expecting.

In fact, here's the entire set of characters you're going to end up with by xoring just those digits:

```
In[0]: set((chr(ord(i)^ord(j)) for j in "abcdef0123456789" for i in "abcdef0123456789"))

Out[0]: {'\x00',
         '\x01',
         '\x02',
         '\x03',
         '\x04',
         '\x05',
         '\x06',
         '\x07',
         '\x08',
         '\t',
         '\n',
         '\x0b',
         '\x0c',
         '\r',
         '\x0e',
         '\x0f',
         'P',
         'Q',
         'R',
         'S',
         'T',
         'U',
         'V',
         'W',
         'X',
         'Y',
         'Z',
         '[',
         '\\',
         ']',
         '^',
         '_'}
```

On a side note, please tell me this is for a class assignment or just for fun. You shouldn't be rolling your own crypto like this.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains some of the \x characters I'm getting.  This is just for just so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your intention is for `strxor` to go through both strings, convert each character to a number in the range 0-15, XOR the corresponding characters from each string together, then convert the results back into characters and return the resulting string. I don't think that `strxor` is doing that - for example, `ord('6')` isn't 6, but rather 54 (the ASCII value of the character). I suspect that this is why you are getting non-hex characters in your input.

Instead of `chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y))`, what I think you want is:

```
def toHexNum(c):
    n = ord(c)
    if n >= ord('0') and n <= ord('9'):
        return n - ord('0')
    elif n >= ord('A') and n <= ord('F'):
        return n - ord('A') + 10
    elif n >= ord('a') and n <= ord('f'):
        return n - ord('a') + 10
    else:
        return None

def fromHexNum(n):
    chars = "0123456789abcdef"
    return chars[n]

def strxor(a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([fromHexNum(toHexNum(x) ^ toHexNum(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join([fromHexNum(toHexNum(x) ^ toHexNum(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])
```

There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but I can't seem to find it - maybe someone whose knowledge of the Python library is stronger than mine can chime in on that note.

Comment: Kyle makes the very good point that, generally speaking, you should be very hesitant to write your own cryptography functions, since there are plenty of perfectly good ones out there in libraries that have been thoroughly examined and tested.

Comment: I'll have to test your code out later but I think you're right.  I did notice that I can sometimes decrypt single character messages.  And other times it doesn't work probably because the ord() function wasn't working the way I though it did.  I'm thinking it might be easier just to do the XOR in binary and change it back to hex after.   It's just for fun too so no worries.